# Variable shift using lookahead in R data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table of numeric predictions for every day in some period of time. These predictions include weekends, which I already shifted to monday using DT syntax:

```
dt[day %in% c("sat", "sun", "mon"), y := sum(y), by = c("year", "week")]
```

then of course, sat and sun can be set 0.

However, there are also non-working days that can be on any day of the week. The predictions for these days need to be shifted to the next working day, taking into account other non-working days (nwd's) and weekends. An example would be:

```
mo tu we th fr (nwd) sa su mo (nwd) tu
---------------------------------------
50 60 60 20 30       0  0  0        20
```

Expected output (friday shifts to next tuesday):

```
mo tu we th fr (nwd) sa su mo (nwd) tu
---------------------------------------
50 60 60 20          0  0  0        50
```

How can I achieve this without using a loop?

### Edit

Sample data:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(
     ds = seq(as.Date('2018-08-13'), as.Date('2018-08-21'), by = 1),
     nwd = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
     pred = c(20, 40, 40, 60, 50, 60, 40, 10, 20))
```

Comment: how about some reproducible data?

Comment: I added some sample data.

Comment: Do you want to aggregate by week, finally? So, is it required to shift the nwd value to exactly the next working day or is it sufficient to have the value included in next week aggregate?

Comment: It should not be aggregated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my first attempt. It marks Saturdays and Sundays as non-working days as well, identifies contiguous streaks of working/non-working days, sums up the predictions for each streak, updates `pred` only for the next working day with the sum of predictions of the previos day, sets `pred` to zero for the non-working days, and removes the helper columns, finally.

```
dt[wday(ds) %in% c(7, 1), nwd := TRUE][
  , streak := rleid(nwd)][
    , streak_sum := sum(pred), by = streak][
      , pred := pred + ifelse(!nwd & rowid(streak) == 1L, shift(streak_sum, fill = 0), 0)][
        (nwd), pred := 0][
          , `:=`(streak = NULL, streak_sum = NULL)][]
```

> ```
>            ds   nwd pred
> 1: 2018-08-13 FALSE   20
> 2: 2018-08-14 FALSE   40
> 3: 2018-08-15 FALSE   40
> 4: 2018-08-16 FALSE   60
> 5: 2018-08-17  TRUE    0
> 6: 2018-08-18  TRUE    0
> 7: 2018-08-19  TRUE    0
> 8: 2018-08-20  TRUE    0
> 9: 2018-08-21 FALSE  180
> ```

---

Here is a more elegant and concise version which uses an *update join*. The trick here is to return also the last day of each streak plus one day which is the begin of the subsequent streak when aggregating the predicitions in each streak.

```
# aggregate by streak
tmp <- dt[wday(ds) %in% c(7, 1), nwd := TRUE][
  , .(nwd = nwd[1], next_day = last(ds) + 1, streak_sum = sum(pred)), by = rleid(nwd)]
# update join but use only non-working streaks
dt[tmp[(nwd)], on = .(ds = next_day), pred := pred + streak_sum][
  (nwd), pred := 0][]
```

> ```
>            ds   nwd pred
> 1: 2018-08-13 FALSE   20
> 2: 2018-08-14 FALSE   40
> 3: 2018-08-15 FALSE   40
> 4: 2018-08-16 FALSE   60
> 5: 2018-08-17  TRUE    0
> 6: 2018-08-18  TRUE    0
> 7: 2018-08-19  TRUE    0
> 8: 2018-08-20  TRUE    0
> 9: 2018-08-21 FALSE  180
> ```

Comment: It works great, thanks. I would really like to understand it, do you mind explaining the code somewhat?

Comment: Have added explanation and a second variant which joins the subtotals of streaks with the next working day.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely understandable.